# Upload to OneDrive Business using JavaScript, outside Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint, office365

Is it possible to upload a file to Office 365 OneDrive Business (SharePoint), using pure JavaScript or jQuery, when running from an external website? (Not a SharePoint site)

I have written some C# code, which authenticates a user, and gets a FormDigestValue. But I don't know where to go from there.

None of the examples I found, seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the Office365 REST API to access OneDrive Business. This works well with JavaScript, especially using jQuery or AngularJS since they are more easy to use refering to REST. 
You will find some examples here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2013/08/13/access-skydrive-pro-using-the-sharepoint-2013-apis.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I have already read this post and many more like it. 
But the problem is uploading using JavaScript / jQuery. 
Since it's a cross domain POST, the server returns an error: 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://<url>' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: ok, your initial post was a little unclear. It doesn't work because of the same-origin domain policies, a security feature in modern browsers. 

Have a look at JSONP (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) as well as the jQuery functions $.getJSON() and $.ajax().

They should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [new](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.ClientLib.JS/) JS library for `O365 APIs`, including OneDrive Business service?
It should support `CORS`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, I am doing it and it works great..

0) Please, have a look here first, it's a great study and helps to understand CORS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-cors-to-access-files-in-office-365

1) Register your app (www.yourdomain.name) in Azure AD (Active Directory) - you must have Office 365 and Azure AD subscription - make sure you change the manifest in Azure AD and set OAuth Implicit = Yes This allows you to get across

2) make sure you're able to receive oAuth token on your site which is registered in Azure AD - again (your.domain.name)

3) Then you AJAX (http://www.yourdomain.name) should have something like this:

```
xhr.open("PUT", OneDriveForBusinessEndPointURL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", fileInput.files[0].type);
xhr.send(fileInput.files[0]);

var FileName = fileInput.files[0]; 

//// Your Endpoint should be like this
var OneDriveForBusinessEndPointURl = https://mydomain-mysharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{folder-id}:/FileName:/content
```

Once you get JSON with xhr.status = 201 or 200, you've won.